# Adding templates on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got this in my controller:

```
$scope.myList= [1, 2, 3];
```

I've got some HTML that looks like this:

```
<h2>Test Dynamic {{ myList.length }}</h2>
<div ng-repeat="ps in myList">
  <ng-include src="'partials/whatever.html'" >
  </ng-include>
</div>

<span data-ng-click="myList.push(1)">Add</span>
```

When I click the span, the count in the  tag increases, but the list doesn't update. This only needs to be marginally functional; let users add an element with the 'Add' button, and remove one with a remove button in the partial template. Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding a duplicate element and you haven't specified a `track by` in your `ng-repeat` function, therefore angular thinks that it's the same element, so you could fix it like this:

```
<h2>Test Dynamic {{ myList.length }}</h2>
<div ng-repeat="ps in myList track by $index">
  <ng-include src="'partials/whatever.html'" >
  </ng-include>
</div>

<span data-ng-click="myList.push(1)">Add</span>
```

Comment: That did it. Damn dupes. Is the process of selecting an element for removal relatively trivial, or a tad more involved? Say the partial contained a remove button, and I wanted it to remove itself from the DOM and Array?

Comment: use myList.splice($index, 1) for click action of 'remove' span

Comment: @MichaelAnthopolous 2 things: 1) if my answer solved your question you should accept the answer. 2) It's trivial, you just need to update your model (do a splice on your 'scope.myList' for example) and that will update the DOM too. Thanks!

Comment: I had to let the timer run out on the answer acceptance. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelAnthopolous oh! I see, sorry about that then, thanks!

Comment: Oh right, $index isn't set because it's outside the ng-repeat.  Sry!